# web service was closed with Fatal Exception

Tags: android, web-services

i was imported one WebService application and it was imported properly and launched properly also,but while running i am getting exception like below.

```
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.prgguru.android.MainActivity.getFahrenheit(MainActivity.java:64)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.prgguru.android.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:101)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.prgguru.android.MainActivity$AsyncCallWS.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-31 15:12:04.969: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  ... 4 more
```

and **MainActivity.java**
    package com.prgguru.android;

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import com.example.webserviceactivity.R;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private String TAG = "PGGURU";
    private static String celcius;
    private static String fahren;
    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Celcius Edit Control
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //Fahrenheit Text control
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        //Button to trigger web service invocation
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button Click Listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Check if Celcius text control is not empty
                if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                    //Get the text control value
                    celcius = et.getText().toString();
                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    //Call execute 
                    task.execute();
                //If text control is empty
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Please enter Celcius");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void getFahrenheit(String celsius) {
        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        //Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
        //Set Name
        celsiusPI.setName("Celsius");
        //Set Value
        celsiusPI.setValue(celsius);
        //Set dataType
        celsiusPI.setType(double.class);
        //Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
        //Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            //Invole web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //Assign it to fahren static variable
            fahren = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            getFahrenheit(celcius);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            tv.setText(fahren + "° F");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            tv.setText("Calculating...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: looks like in `doInBackground()` you are calling a function in another class...not in `AsyncCallWS`. you should move `getFahrenheit()` into `AsyncCallWS` (or just put the code in `doInBackground()`. also your call to `AsyncCallWS` doesn't pass any parameters so it should be declared (in this case) `...extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>`. i would suggest passing in your variable `celcius` to keep things clean.

Comment: I am getting exception at 
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); in public void getFahrenheit(String celsius) method

Comment: it's odd that the `getFahrenheit()` function in is `MainActivity` rather than in your AsyncTask. I guess it's working because it's `public`, but it's bad form regardless. you are not calling it in `MainActivity`...right? move it to your AsyncTask class...once you have it cleaned up, lemme know what you're seeing.